# Can react-navigation update the location when changing route?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

I am working on a react-native project built with expo SDK36.

I am using [`react-navigation`](https://reactnavigation.org/) for building my navigation.

So far, I am reading the documentation and testing the basic example and can't find a way to update the window `location`.

Is it possible to have some sort of `browserHistory` and change route base on this web building a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it doesn't. It's recommended to use React Router for web for now.